# PyPDF2 not printing for pdf File Version 1.4 and below

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am not able to print the content of a pdf file with PDF version is 1.4 or less in Python 3.x.
The code works fine for pdf files with PDF version 1.5 and above.
The code is as follows:

```py
import PyPDF2 

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('C:/Users/ravi/Documents/pdf-sample.pdf') 
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0) 
print(pageObj.extractText())
```

Comment: You should post the error you're getting and share the problematic PDF file if possible.

Comment: No error appears on the screen. print() function does not print anything. There is no output produced. For the pdf files, whose PDF version is 1.5 and above, the output appears. You can reproduce the situation by taking two pdf files, one with version less than 1.5 and other with more than or equal to 1.5. The Version number can be checked by opening the pfd and clicking on File menu>properties.

Comment: Please share an example PDF file for which printing fails.